# Why use opto-isolation in this way?

Tags: opto-isolator, ground-loop

I'm synchronizing two FLIR cameras and FLIR's use of opto-isolation in [this](https://www.ptgrey.com/KB/11052) document doesn't make sense to me.  Could someone explain the benefits of using opto-couplers as FLIR describes?

The two cameras are both connected to one computer via USB3.0 cables.  In order to synchronize the cameras, a 6-pin GPIO cable is used to connect the two cameras directly.  One of the cameras is configured as "primary" and is triggered to capture images by software on the computer.  The other camera is configured as "secondary" and is triggered by the "primary" camera through the GPIO cable.

This is the pinout for the GPIO port coming out of each camera.
[image: GPIO port pinout]

And this is the cable wiring diagram to connect the cameras together.
[image: GPIO cable wiring diagram]

I feel like I just wouldn't have done it this way, but that doesn't really matter.  Could someone explain to me why they *did* do it this way?  At the very least, this setup creates a ground loop between the 2 USB cables and the 1 GPIO cable.  I would think that the opto-isolation would be used to prevent exactly this.  Could someone elaborate?  Thanks

Comment: questions about the use of appliances... and anyway it's hard to guess what's behind those pin labels.

Comment: why don't you direct your concern about the ground loop to the FLIR manufacturer?

Comment: Just what side of the optocouplers do you think a possible ground loop would be at? Not at the FLIR sensors.

Comment: How is it not a ground loop?  Computer GND -> USB GND -> Camera 1 GND -> GPIO cable GND (pin 6) -> Camera 2 GND -> USB GND -> Computer GND.  Thats a loop.  The diagram connects the two brown pins and that confuses me.  If it's obvious, please explain because I'm missing it.

Comment: To address Jasen's comment.  I'm not really asking about this application; my cameras are already working.  I'm asking about how to use opto-couplers and why FLIR, a company that knows their stuff when it comes to circuits, is using opto-couplers in a way that seems odd.  I assume I am missing something.

Comment: I agree with the OP that this is a design question and not a use question.